# Zephir extension class in Global space

Tags: php, zephir

Is it possible to create a [Zephir](http://zephir-lang.com/) extension that exposes classes in the [PHP Global space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)?

> Without any namespace definition, all class and function definitions are placed into the global space

Any attempts to leave out a namespace provides the following error and all the [documentation examples](http://docs.zephir-lang.com/en/latest/oop.html) explicitly use one.

```
[sean3z:~/project] $ zephir build
Zephir\CompilerException: A namespace is required in /Users/sean3z/project/project/Registry.zep on line 3

    class Registry extends \ArrayObject {
    ----^
```